# telnet using internal ip from command line in amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In one of my amazon aws server installed memcahed server in port 11211.
Now i ssh to that server and run this command

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 11211
```

I get connected to and can access memcache data. 
If i use private or public ip instead of `127.0.0.1`

```
telnet <private ip> 11211
```

i get this

> telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Lets call this server `master` server where `memcached` is installed.
If i now ssh to other app server and run this command

```
telnet <private ip> 11211
```

get the same error. But the `master` server security group has this inbound rules.

> All traffic All All sg-xxxxxx (app server)

Should we not get access to all services running in our master server from app servers?

Comment: If you run this `netstat -nap | grep LISTE | grep tcp | grep 11211` from memcached instance's shell, what is the output?

Comment: If i ssh to server where memcached is installed i get `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1333/memcached`

Comment: Check `/etc/memcached.conf` and change `-l 127.0.0.1` to `-l 0.0.0.0` and restart memcached service